# python confirm that dict(headers) contain a specific string

Tags: python, wordpress

I am trying to find a string in the headers of response after login in Wordpress script, so I tried with this find method:

```
import urllib, urllib2, os, sys, requests , re
....
....
req = urllib2.Request(url, urllib.urlencode(dict(data)), dict(headers))
response = urllib2.urlopen(req)
res = dict(response.headers)
res1 = 'wp-admin'
if res.find(res1) >= 0:
 print 'wp-admin exist in dict(response.headers)'
```

and i get this error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\wp2\wp12.py", line 29, in <module>
    if res.find(res1) >= 0:
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'find'
```

Is there any idea  confirm that dict(headers) contain 'wp-admin' or transform the dict(headers) into text to use find function correctly?

Comment: Why not look at a specific header? The string is not going to be found in the `Content-Type` or `Transport-Encoding` headers, for example.

Comment: yeah that another problem look :
stackoverflow.com/questions/25245805

Comment: Why not just do `if res1 in res.values()` or `if res1 in res.keys()`.

Comment: @ZWiki: that'll only match whole keys or values.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: that's correct
there is a way to transform the dict(response.headers) to text ? and then use the find function ?

Comment: @user3925763: That'd be an inefficient way to solve your problem; I am looking for a duplicate, but you can just use a loop instead; `any('wp-admin' in v for v in response.headers.values())`.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: a 10000000 thanks man !!!

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: can you put it like an answer so i mark it as the correct answer ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general, to find all items in a dict where the value contains a string:

```
[(key, value) for (key, value) in the_dict.items() if search_string in value]
```

(On python 2.x, use `iteritems` for efficiency.)

If you only need to know if it's there at all:

```
any(search_string in value for value in the_dict.values())
```

(On python 2.x you can use `itervalues` as well)

Comment: that helps a lot , thanks mate ! 
can you take a look in this question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25245805
have a nice day :)

Answer (score 0):

The error message is letting you know that the datatype *dict* doesn't have a *find* method available to it like other datatypes might.  But the good news for you is that response.headers is already in a dictionary-like format so you can search for your "wp-admin" directly.

```
import urllib2

url = "http://www.google.com"
response = urllib2.urlopen(url)

for headername in response.headers:
    print headername, response.headers[headername]

if "wp-admin" in response.headers:
    print "header found"
```

It's just like this as well:

```
a = {"wp-admin":"value1",
         "header2":"value2"} 
if "wp-admin" in a:
         print "Found header"
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, don't use `str.find()` to test for the presence of a substring; use `in` membership testing instead:

```
>>> 'foo' in 'there was once a foo that barred a bar'
True
>>> 'foo' in 'spam, ham and eggs'
False
```

To test for a substring in *all* values of a dictionary, loop over all values. To just test for the presence, use membership tests against each one. The [`any()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) with a generator expression makes that a little more efficient by looping only enough to find a match:

```
if any('wp-admin' in v for v in response.headers.itervalues()):
```

Here [`dict.itervalues()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.itervalues) yields all values in a dictionary lazily when looped over.

However, with request headers I'd normally expect the value to show up in just *one* header; you'd be better of looking for that specific header:

```
if 'wp-admin' in response.headers.get('set-cookie', ''):
```

where the `.get()` method will return `''` if the `Set-Cookie` header is not present.